# Floating div issue

Tags: html

I have an issue with floating divs. I have a container st to fixed width, and I have child elements inside that which are all div elements. What I want is that, I need two elements to be shown in a row. The code that I wrote is as follows.

***CSS***

```
#container
    {
        width: 400px;
    }
    .item1
    {
        width: 180px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        float: left;
        margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    }
    .item2
    {
        width: 180px;
        height: 250px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        float: left;
        margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
        <div class="item1">1</div>
        <div class="item1">2</div>
        <div class="item1">3</div>
        <div class="item1">4</div>
        <div class="item1">5</div>
        <div class="item1">6</div>
        <div class="item1">7</div>
        <div class="item1">8</div>
        <div class="item1">9</div>
    </div>
```

This can be viewed at [**Demo1**](http://jsfiddle.net/9SeKx/)

But what I want is like this [**result**](http://jsfiddle.net/9SeKx/1/). The only thing is that the height of the individual items can be different.

Hope I have made everything clear.

Thanks in advance

***Additional clarification***

The content elements will be generated dynamically in server and will be passed to the client.

Also the order should be like 1,2,3,4,...

The only thing is that in a row there should be two items and the first one should be aligned to the left side of the container.

Comment: Do you want each pair to be on a new line (1 and 2, 3 and 4, etc.), or do you want everything to fill in the gaps?

Comment: Yes, I need each pair to be in a new line. Like 1 and 2 will be in the first row, 2 and 3 will be in the second...

Answer (score 0):

You can't accomplish that with CSS only, but there is a jQuery plugin to do the trick. It's called [**jQuery Masonry**](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/), give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You need a second wrapper:

```
<div id="container">
        <div class="wrapper"><div class="item1">1</div></div>
        <div class="wrapper"><div class="item1">2</div></div>
        ...
</div>
```

Float the wrapper and give it a fixed size. The items inside can have their own height.

I prefer using lists for this type of thing. Better HTML semantics.

```
<div class="container">
   <ul>
       <li><div class="item1">1</div></li>
       <li><div class="item2">2</div></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

style:

```
.container ul {
    width:400px;
}

.container li {
    float:left;
    height:200px;
    width:180px;

}
```

Comment: The content without CSS is ordered different this way, maybe that's not what rahul wants. The order in your example is `1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8`

Comment: For this I need a logic to be implemented in server side to fill the contents in the wrapper. Is there any other way by which I can use the same HTML and by CSS only I can achieve the desired result?

Comment: @Diodeus Notice the large gap between the 3/4 pairing and 5/6, I think we're trying to avoid static row heights here.

Comment: You can't have an aligned grid with floats without having static heights. End of story.

Comment: @Diodeus Unless he can modify the output to include additional formatting, right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want each pair of items to be in a row, and you have control over the dynamic generation of the content, see my edits to your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9SeKx/2/)

To summarize:

Markup -

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="itemrow">
        <div class="item1">1</div>
        <div class="item1">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemrow">
        <div class="item2">3</div>
        <div class="item1">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemrow">
        <div class="item2">5</div>
        <div class="item1">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemrow">
        <div class="item1">7</div>
        <div class="item2">8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemrow">
        <div class="item1">9</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
    #container
    {
        width: 400px;
    }
    .itemrow
    {
        float: left;
        clear: both;
    }
    .item1
    {
        width: 180px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        float: left;
        margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    }
    .item2
    {
        width: 190px;
        height: 250px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        float: left;
        margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    }
```

Edit: Just read your above comment about having to edit the server side logic for rendering. Obviously this will only work if you can control that.

Answer (score -1):

you're specifying item2 to be 10 pixels wider than item1 so I'm not clear on what you're trying to do....